# InfluxDB for seismic data

Tags: node.js, influxdb, acceleration

I am experimenting with InfluxDB for storing seismic data. That means multiple concurrent writes of data from sensors. Typical sensor samples data at 200 to 1000 samples per second per channel. What is the best approach to write this? The idea is that each write to DB e.g. each Point is an array of 200 or 1000 floats with one single timestamp. Can the **Point **class of the influxdb-client accept such array as value?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

simple test with InfluxDB container